# Implement Federated Auth for Asp.net Core headless

Tags: federated-authentication

I have a Sitecore 10 application running in container with ASP.Net core Headless mode.
I want to implement a federated authentication for my CD site.
But is it possible ? As per the below document its not clear
https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/authentication/federated-auth
"This approach will not work in Headless or Connected modes, as it depends on browser requests directly to Sitecore. It may be possible to mock in Disconnected mode."